# How to remove the already opened popup in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I googled and search SO but can't find anything relates to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/Ad22d/90/

In this fiddle, cloned the table rows using **`ADD ROW`** in that table row  click **Add Expenses** shows the `popup` it is also cloned when click the `PLUS icon`...

My problem starts here now i click the `first row add expense button`, **3 rows cloned** in popup then click the `second row add expenses` it shows three rows but i need to `show only one column` (that is default one)...

Please suggest some idea...Thank You

Comment: You're going to have to instantiate a new/fresh one for each worker based on the underlying data.  Make a function which takes a basic unpopulated template of the pop-up and then adds more rows if there are more expenses etc. for each worker and show it once that's complete.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker thanks for your reply..i understand but i am new to javascript and jquery so i can't do exactly.

Comment: This should get you going.  I've had to scope the functions to the `window` object because of the way jsfiddle works with frames . http://jsfiddle.net/TYw57/1/
Also suggest you do the cloning etc with jQuery, plenty of documentation on the jQuery website for that.

Comment: Can you not use window.close()?

Answer (score 2):

I have added following method on `addExpenses` buttons (i.e. Add `onclick="addExpenses();"` attribute to all `addExpenses` buttons.)

```
function addExpenses()
{
  var row = document.getElementById("expenseTable");
  var table = document.getElementById("expenseParticulars");
  var rowcount=table.rows.length-1;
  for(var i=2;i<=rowcount;)
  {
    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowcount--;
  }
  var clone = row.rows[1];
  var addExpenses = clone.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  addExpenses.disabled = false;
  counter=2;
}
```

Please refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ad22d/103/) jsfiddle.

Comment: this what i did in my application but i feel this is not a correct way thats why i am not write my answer here...+1 for your effort